# Is it possible to host ASP.net website with XAMPP?

Tags: asp.net, xampp

I am trying to deploy my ASP.net webprog and i want it to deploy via XAMPP is it possible?, i already edited the configuration in httpd-xampp and add the script but i was getting error when i tried to run the apache. Can you give me some advice, tips regarding hosting asp.net in XAMPP

```
 Error: cannot load modules/mod_aspdotnet.so into server
```

Comment: check this link for step by step process. [How to run ASP.Net on XAMPP](http://xehroz.tumblr.com/post/43884721903/how-to-run-aspnet-on-xampp)

Comment: thanks for the reply, i already did that, with some research tells apache 2.4 is not supported by mod_aspdotnet, is there other option to deploy my ASP project?

Comment: any update on this thread ? i still couldn't find any way to connect aspx to xampp server.